# getNode() method not found in gatsby-node.js with the latest version of Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Am working through the official Gatsby tutorial [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/). Up until step 7 everything worked 100% fine. In step 7 "Programmatically create pages from data", this snippet is listed for `gatsby-node.js` (as is, no imports):

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node }) => {
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const fileNode = getNode(node.parent)
    console.log(`\n`, fileNode.relativePath)
  }
}
```

However, when running `gatsby develop` I get: **`ReferenceError: getNode is not defined`**. I have googled it up for quite some time, and it seems that there may have been some breaking changes recently in the latest versions of Gatsby. Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for this and how to fix the missing reference? Maybe some module should be imported?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have just figured out the answer. It was my own typo. I did not add the second `getNode` parameter to the `onCreateNode` function:

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode }) => {
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const fileNode = getNode(node.parent)
    console.log(`\n`, fileNode.relativePath)
  }
}
```

Comment: Great catch.  I have counter the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: You are not the only ones.

Comment: A contributor just updated this section of the tutorial to spell out the need to include `getNode` in the function params for `OnCreateNode` which will hopefully help others in the future: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/23775 seeing a handful of people here helped make that improvement to the docs so thanks to each of you!